# Access elements by index in an FTL Template

Tags: freemarker

Need to access 1st and 2nd element of a list in the template.

My Java code:

```
myMap.put("key", Arrays.asList("val1", "val2");
```

My FTL Template:

```
<#list myMap?keys as key> 
${myMap[key][0]}, ${myMap[key][1]}
```

<-- the line above fails with undefined expression on myMap[key][0]. I checked and myMap[key] is a SimpleSequence. Also, tried ${myMap[key]?first} and that failed with the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: I just did something similar and did an assign first.  Like <#assign x = myMap[key]>  It worked for my purposes, hopefully it would for yours too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[0]` and `[1]` are fine for this, but it looks like that either the sequence has 0 elements, or those elements are `null`. What does `${myMap[key]?size}` print? BTW, you can write `${myMap[key][0]!'some default'}` if you want to get a value even if the item is non-existant or `null`.

Comment: The problem was a null element, the defaulting syntax did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you put the List into your 'myMap' object with the key: "key" then try and access it with they key: "keys".

This is why you were getting an undefined expression, to correct it:

```
<#list myMap?key as k> 
${myMap[k][0]}, ${myMap[k][1]}
```

or of course you could change your java code to

```
myMap.put("keys", Arrays.asList("val1", "val2");
```

and use the ftl code as is.